# Reference entity field name is empty in primary entity view CRM2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created many to one relationship b/w Location and Appointment entities. I am creating a view in Appointment to show all appointments with their location names but when I do this, location columns showed up with empty values.

This view is out of the box.

Here it is I add location name field in appointment view:

[image]

Any ideas why location name is appearing empty in appointment view?

Thanks.

Comment: you created one-to-many or many-to-many relationship between location and appointment?

Comment: there is 1:N relationship b/w Location and appointment.
1:N means
(Primary entity-> Location,
Related entity-> Appointment
)

Comment: just to be sure, in this way you have a lookup inside appointment entity to choose a single location, right?

Comment: no... there is multi-value lookup on Location entity of type appointment.

Comment: By your screenshot I think there is also the 1:N relationship in the opposite way. However choose Appointment as record type in the first dropdown, and check if there is a Location field. The regarding type is when the regarding field is selected with a location record, and is not your case.

Comment: Is the name field actually populated?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special if all you want is the name.

If Location is the primary entity which is selected in a specific lookup field on the Appointment record, called something like "Location", then just add this field from Appointment in the view.

You don't have to explicitly fetch it from the Location record because although a lookup stores the GUID of the target record, CRM interprets this view to mean you want to see the primary field (name) of the primary entity, not the actual GUID. What you see in the lookup field on the form will be the same as what you see in the view.

If you want a field other than the name, then you do need to choose the primary entity in your list, but not via the "Regarding" relationship, but whatever your actual custom relationship is called - probably just "Location"